# What is exactly a default (classful) network mask?

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I know that each IP class has a default network mask (class A: 255.0.0.0, class B: 255.255.0.0 and class C: 255.255.255.0).

I have been reading the subnetting.net tutorial and they use the default (classful) network mask for subnetting (Question Type 2 Written Example), but on the other hand I read all the time that IP classes are obsolete.

What is exactly a default network mask?
Is it needed for subnetting?
Am I confusing concepts? (I suspect I am)

Please help, this is burning my head.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address can never become obsolete a similar anology can be your home address becoming obsolete. The fact that IPv4 addresses are drying up Because there are that many devices in the globe now which is greater than the number of ip's available. That's why we are moving to IPv6...

A subnet mask is a number that defines a range of IP addresses available within a network. A single subnet mask limits the number of valid IPs for a specific network. Multiple subnet masks can organize a single network into smaller networks (called subnetworks or subnets).
For exp a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 allows for close to 256 unique hosts within the network (since not all 256 IP addresses can be used).see [Why do we need subnet mask?](https://superuser.com/questions/394385/why-do-we-need-subnet-mask)

Comment: I didn't say that IP is obsolete, I was talking about IP classes.

Comment: see [Does CIDR really “do away” with IP address classes?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19840/does-cidr-really-do-away-with-ip-address-classes)

Comment: Thank you! That is very useful.